# Access Multiple Elements Data Attributes with JQuery On Change Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to create a way to re-arrange menu items. I am using this Github library: https://github.com/ShinDarth/Nestable

I added two data attributes `data-parent` and `data-sub` to my `<li>`.

I am attempting to update those attributes when an item is re-arranged.

So if an item is placed as a child, its data attribute, `data-parent`, would be the `data-id` of its parent.
Expanding on that, the parent's own `data-sub` would become true or `1`, meaning it has sub-items.

Un-parenting a child, would set both the parent and the child's `data-parent` and `data-sub` to 0. Since neither are have sub-objects or parents.

Example:

Take these two items. Notice that `data-parent` and `data-sub` are both set to zero.

```
<div class="dd nestable">
    <ol class="dd-list">
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="1" data-name="MenuName1"  data-sub="0" data-parent="0" data-new="0" data-deleted="0">
        <div class="dd-handle">MenuName1</div>
    </li>

    <li class="dd-item" data-id="2" data-name="MenuName2"  data-sub="0" data-parent="0" data-new="0" data-deleted="0">
        <div class="dd-handle">MenuName</div>
    </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Using the *Nestable* library to move `MenuName2` as a child of `MenuName1` would result in the below.

```
<div class="dd nestable">
    <ol class="dd-list">
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="1" data-name="MenuName1" data-sub="1" data-parent="0" data-new="0" data-deleted="0">
     <div class="dd-handle">MenuName1</div>
      <ol class="dd-list">
       <li class="dd-item" data-id="2" data-name="MenuName2" data-sub="0" data-parent="1" data-new="0" data-deleted="0">
        <div class="dd-handle">MenuName</div>
       </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

In the above code,

- ***MenuName1*** - `data-sub="1"` (Since it has a child)
- ***MenuName2*** - `data-parent="1"` (The *1*, is the `data-id` of the parent, in this case 1)

I thought the `onChange()` event would be a good place to update. But I can't seem to access any of the data elements.

```
$('.dd').on('change', function (e) {
   /* on change event */
  var target = $(e.target);
  console.log("reordered " + JSON.stringify(e));
});
```

***How can I access the data attributes of the parent and the child to manipulate them?***

Comment: Where is the class 'dd' in your html code? Anyways `change` event works for input fields not for decorator or read only elements.

Comment: On the the github website the menu is wrapped in a div with the class "dd nestable". In your example the menu is not enclosed in a div with the calss "dd". Is there the root of your problem?

Comment: It is wrapped in the dd div. I left it out for brevity.

Comment: @YousafHassan  I updated the question with the dd

Answer (score 0):

According to the github website example you should use

```
$('.dd.nestable').on('change', .... )
```

Might this be your solution?